# Need to Create a 3 level approval Process, Unable to identify how to do it

Tags: approval-process, approval-step, approve-action

I need to create , a three level approval process. My organization as 67 users. so I cant just manually fed the users.

I have  three Roles

- Thailand Sales Rep
- Thailand Sales Manager
- Thailand Sales Director

When criteria 1 is met , It should go to Sales Rep for approval

WHen criteria 2 is met , It should go the that paticular Sales Rep's Manager , i.e. the Thailand Sales Manager

When criteria 3 is met , It should go to that paticular Sales Rep's Manager and once Sales Manager approves, It should go to Sales Director , for validation.

There are some status field updates also , But as of now. i am not getting. how to fix this problem. 
I am pretty sure , this can not be done with the Standard approval process only.

But how I can achieve this.

Comment: You can refer to Salesforce guide: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Approval_Processes

Comment: On which object you want to create the approval process?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be achieved by out-of-box Approval process functionality.

You need to create 3 queues based on the roles.

Defining Thailand Sales Rep Queue, choose `Thailand Sales Rep` role. Same way for those roles.

In the Approval Steps, based on the criteria assign it to the respective queue.

[image: Assigned Approvers]

Secondly, to auto-submit the from one approval process to other approval process based on the field update, you should leverage process builder.

Comment: But , when it goes to the queue, It doesnt go to the Sales Rep , who has created the offer. Secondly , When it goes to Sales Manager queue, I want the Sales Rep already existing manager , to validate it.  How do I achieve this

Comment: you first brainstorm different options, explore all the options in DE or sandbox and put the issue which you are facing.

Comment: I already have created this for my organization. The issue is.. That it goes to Sales Rep Manager, when it meets second criteria.. That is because , in the approval state, I have maintained manager.
However, when it meets third criteria.. There is no way , by which I can make it first go to Sales manager for approval, and post his approval. go to Sales Director

Comment: to meet 3rd criteria you need to create 2 approval processes and you can create separate internal status based on which you can submit for approval when first one is approved. This submission should be done by process builder

Comment: Hi Santanu,

Can you suggest how can I do it ?

If you can help me building this one.. We are very close to go-live.. and I dnt see... any idea. how ot it..


Since, there is a field update on every level of approval. I have actually created 3 approval processes.. But nothing seems to work for me

Comment: I see you didn't accept any of your previous answers, are those not helping you getting the results? Members are investigating their time to help you but no acknowledgment!

Comment: Hi Santanu,
For the suggestiong for using Queue.

I commented. though I will repeaT

While using queues, There is no surity over, who will be getting the approval request.

But I want, Only the Sales Rep manager to approve it. The manager is maintained in the Users Object.
For the third level validation.

I require , first the Sales Rep manager , and after his approval , it should be sent to Sales Rep Director.. The one who's maintained as manager for Sales Rep Manager